# Generate mp3 from midi

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, midi

I need to generate MP3 files from MIDI files in batch. Is there a library that can do that? Preferably open source and written in .NET

Comment: @yodaj007: I don't think LAME can read MIDI... it would have to be converted to a waveform first.

Comment: Search for soundfonts. I think FruitLoops can convert MIDI to mp3, if you have the soundfonts.

Comment: the short answer - not possible, but I'd be curious to know what you are actually trying to accomplish. Maybe there is another way to get there.

Comment: I have about 80 compositions written in MIDI and I want to convert them in to MP3 so they can be played on all computers and sound the same.

Comment: http://is.gd/igp4m -- I've seen so many questions about converting MIDI to audio I had to write this.  Please take the time to read it if you are considering writing some software system which needs to do that.

Comment: This topic is discussed also in topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321881/need-a-library-that-generates-wave-from-midi/, perhaps you could find some information there, particularly in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321881/need-a-library-that-generates-wave-from-midi/7771403#7771403). Resulting wave can then be encoded to MP3 or any format you like. For WAVE encoding to MP3 there in [example project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx) using LAME encoder dll.

Answer (score 2):

**You can convert midis to mp3s using a batch file and vlc.**

As it states in the [VLC wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Midi) to play midis in Windows you need version 1.1.0 as well as a sound font. This version is currently in testing so can be downloaded from http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/testing/

Once you have set up midi support according to the [wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Midi) and tested it(by playing a midi). You can set up your batch file.

The command I used to convert a single midi to mp3 is

```
C:\Users\Public\Music>"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I dummy -vvv "australia.mid" --sout=#transcode{acodec="mp3",ab="512","channels=2"}:standard{access="file",mux="raw",dst="australia.mp3"} vlc://quit
```

The above command keeps both files in the same folder.
I have adapted this command from the information found on the [VLC wiki- How_to_Batch_Encode](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Batch_Encode)

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest struggle is converting from midi to a waveform of any format. Eg midi doesn't specify what a piano sounds like, so every midi player will sound different.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `timidity` and `lame`:

```
timidity myMidiFile.midi -Ow -o - | lame - audioOutput.mp3"
```

For all your batch needs, use these programs in a bach script.

If it has to be C related, try checking out [Csound](http://www.csounds.com/).

For .NET, check out [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).